# FORTRAN 90 - Input Syntax Error

Tags: input, io, syntax-error, fortran90

This should be an easy one.. I can't figure out why my read statement has a syntax error. I have a file 7477 lines long and I want each of those variables to correspond in each line like my format specifies. Any help here would be great. Thanks!

```
implicit none

integer :: spe, flen = 7477, i
real, dimension (7477)::  wnum,s,A,abh
character :: other
integer :: lun = 11

write(*,*) 'Opening File!'
open(lun,file ='h2o_allbands',status = 'old',action ='read')
write(*,*) 'Success!'


17 format (1x,i2,3x,F9.6,1x,E9.3,1x,E9.3,F5.5,A120)

do i = 1, 7477
   read(lun,17) spe(i),wnum(i),s(i),A(i),abh(i),other
   write(*,*) wnum(i)
 end do
```

Comment: Did you intent `other` to be a single character, or a `character*(LEN=120)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read has `spe(i)` as an input list item.  `spe` is not declared as an array, so the compiler probably thinks `spe(i)` is a reference to an integer function.  You cannot read "into" the result of a plain integer function.

Perhaps `spe` should be declared as an array?

Comment: +1. No idea why this was not upvoted yet. By the way as one of the top users of the FORTRAN tag, I thought you'd be delighted to see this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6252/5 on a brand new SE site!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a line from your input file, it is difficult to say what the exact problem is: However:

- First of all, you should not use a `format` statement when *reading* entities (unless in special cases), as this can lead to all sort of different errors, if your line is not well formatted for whatever reasons. So just replace the read line with:

  ```
  read(lun,*) spe(i), wnum(i), s(i), A(i), abh(i), other
  ```
- If all the lines are read in well apart the last one, then make sure, that you have a newline at the end of the last line.

Comment: hmm. I dont see how this would work without using the format specifier. Here is the first part of the first line of my text file with the numbers I need. The last 3 are scrunched together!

 11   10.714931 2.528E-24 6.118E-06.0773.2324

Comment: If the input is fixed format then an explicit format is a far more robust approach.  List directed formatting has some quite obscure features that have tripped up many (including myself) over time - better to get an error than for your program to carry on silently with bad input.  I avoid it in production code even for "free format" stuff - it is friendlier to your users to read and parse the line in your own code.

Comment: OK, if the input is fixed formatted, especially when numbers are scrunched together, probably fixed format input is the only way to go. However, input entered by users fixed format can be cumbersome: for example `ṙead(*, "(F4.2)") xx` would result in `-1.23` if the user enters `-123`.